# How to restart count down timer if I come back to activity?

Tags: android, countdown, back, restart, countdowntimer

I have an entrance layout which needs to be seen for 3 seconds. If I start the app it stays 3 seconds and `activity` changes, that's okay but the problem is, if I come back to this `activity` via backpress of smartphone while I am using the app `avtivity` doesn't change after 3 seconds. I am new and couldn't find out problem ? Could you please help me ? Thanks

```
public class A1CoverPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.a1cover_page);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.a0action_bar);

        new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                EditText mTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
                mTextField.setText(" Loading... ");

                ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.amblem);    
            }

            public void onFinish() {

                Intent intent = new Intent(A1CoverPage.this, A2ExperimentCalibration.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }.start();    
    }
```

Comment: if you know how to restart it by code, then you should put it inside the `onResume` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onCreate` will be executed only first time , when your activity is created , but when you come back to this activity then `onCreate` will not be executed again.

so `override` `onstart` method in `Activity` and move your code inside `onstart`

```
EditText mTextField;    
ImageView mImageView;
// ^^^^ declare views references 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.a1cover_page);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.a0action_bar);    

    mTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    // ^^^ initialize views
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {    
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {    
            mTextField.setText(" Loading... ");    
            mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.amblem);
        }

        public void onFinish() {    
            Intent intent = new Intent(A1CoverPage.this, A2ExperimentCalibration.class);
            startActivity(intent);    
        }
    }.start();
}
```

**Improvements :** Declare your view in class and initialize them in `onCreate` instead of internalizing them everytime in your timer anonymous class

Answer (score 0):

move your `CountDownTimer` inside `onStart()` methodsimilar to this:

```
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            EditText mTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            mTextField.setText(" Loading... ");

            ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.amblem);

        }

        public void onFinish() {

            Intent intent = new Intent(A1CoverPage.this, A2ExperimentCalibration.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }.start();
    }
```